# Change "~/foo" to "approot/foo" from inside Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the `global.asax` of my MVC app, I have a string like `"~/foo"`. I have to generate a client-side script (JavaScript) and pass the value of this path `"~/foo"` to that script.

However, before passing that path, I want that the path must resolve to `"approot/foo"` where `approot` is the application's root.

So, for e.g. I deploy my application in IIS under a new website named `Ding` (for want of a better word), the path `"~/foo"` must resolve to `"/Ding/foo"`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `VirtualPathUtility` class there's a bunch of methods there to help you.

In your case you want `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute()`.

For example:

```
var path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/foo");
```

Should resolve how you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was simple and quick.